# What is the difference between fragen and nachfragen?

Tags: verb-usage

What is the difference between *fragen* and *nachfragen*? The question was to translate:

> I would ask.

I translated that as: *Ich würde fragen*, but it was marked wrong. The correct answer was: *Ich würde nachfragen.*

Comment: Was the sentence given without any context at all?

Comment: @Janka I think it's fine to use *nachfragen* for first-time questions, too. But you are right, context matters and "Ich würde fragen" should usually not have been marked wrong.

Answer (score 9):

*Fragen* is a very open act and would be the closest translation to the word "to ask". It can be used almost always as the translation, but sometimes it wouldn't be a good form.

*Nachfragen* on the other hand is more specific than *fragen*: it often means that you're asking for confirmation like "Is this true?" or "Did you say that" or "what's my job here?" like Janka stated in his/her comment. Another thing about *nachfragen* is that it implies interaction in terms of getting an answer: "to ask yourself" would only translate to "sich etwas fragen" (nachfragen would be wrong here). When you use *nachfragen* you want confirmation/information from another person/group/office/etc.

The simplest separation of those word however is to what/who the asking refers: "Asking someone" is always "*fragen*". "Asking about a state of something" almost always translates to "*nachfragen*"

Examples:

- Ich muss nachfragen, *wann die Feier ist* (State: Time of something)
- Ich frage *meinen Bruder*, wann die Feier ist (asking someone: my brother)
- Wir werden nachfragen, *welche Unterlagen benötigt werden* (State: needed Documents for something)
- Wir werden *den Beamten* fragen, welche Unterlagen benötigt werden (asking someone: official)

Now more generalized:

- Ich frage die *(Person/Gruppe/etc)* etwas
- Ich frage nach, wie/ob/was/etc. *(ein bestimmter Sachverhalt)*
- Ich frage *bei* (Person/Gruppe/etc.) nach, (ein bestimmter Sachverhalt)

Italic words are the indicator whether *fragen* or *nachfragen* should be used.

As in most things in the German language, there are always some exceptions to this. But it's a good orientation.

To your example: I assume the "I would ask" refers to something said before, and if it's a sentence like "how does this work?" or "when will they come?", which are both asking about a state (functionality/time of the arrival). In that case, it would apply to the former sentences' kind of question and therefore be translated to "ich würde nachfragen".

Comment: Nachfragen also has one more meaning - as a verb derived from Nachfrage (= demand in economical meaning) usually used in passiv: Diese Ware wird kaum nachgefragt (there is a low demand for this good - lit. this good is seldom asked for).

Comment: True, but Ithink this would be confusing in this context.

Comment: also there are similarities to this in English: die Frage - the question; nachfragen (in the meaning of demand) - to request.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the context, *nachfragen* could be more appropriately translated with *to inquire*, while *fragen* to me is more of a direct translation of *to ask*.

> Ich werde mal auf dem Amt nachfragen, wie es mit meinem Antrag steht.
>
> I'll inquire about the status of my application from the bureau.

Comment: Thank you for this simple, easy to remember answer.